# Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

i'am somewhat new to selenuium multithreading and need some pointers as how to approach this case, as I'm currently stumped.

```
public static class MultiThreadingExample extends Thread {
    String browserType;
    List<String> localList;
    String threadName="";
    
    public MultiThreadingex(String name, String browserType, List<String> localList, String threadName) {
        super(name);
        this.browserType = browserType;
        this.localList = localList;
        this.threadName=threadName;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread starts " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

        String threadname = Thread.currentThread().getName();

        System.out.println(threadname);

        try {
            driver = setUp(this.browserType, threadName);
            if (threadname.contains("thread1")) {
                driver1= testRun(localList, driver); //error here
            }
            if (threadname.contains("thread2"))
                driver2= testRun(localList, driver);
            if (threadname.contains("thread3"))
                driver3= testRun(localList, driver);
            
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
public WebDriver setUp(String browserType, String threadName) throws Exception { 
//returns the driver setup if its either firefox, internetEx, chromo (complete)
}

public void testRun(List<String> localList, WebDriver drivers) throws Exception { //error here on the void bit...
//attempts to find and filter the matching cases (complete)
}
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    List<String> globalList = Arrays.stream(listofPRI).collect(Collectors.toList());

    seleniumTest.divideArrayList(globalList, 3);
    Thread t1 = new MultiThreadingex("Thread Chrome", "Chrome", firstList, "thread1");
    Thread t2 = new MultiThreadingex("Thread Chrome", "Chrome", secondList, "thread2");
    Thread t3 = new MultiThreadingex("Thread Chrome", "Chrome", thirdList, "thread3");

    System.out.println("starting Threads (3)");

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();

    System.out.println("Thread has started");

}
```

The whole purpose of the void testRun is to not return any expected value, but to filter and compare from the arraylist if it is matching or not.
However, due to "Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to WebDriver" its expecting a return value. Therefore, its expecting the
"public void testRun" to be changed to "public WebDriver testRun"
with return statement, which would render the WebDriver setup invalid as the find webelement invalid...

I've tried looking into other example/error where the case is similar but the approach is slightly different than what I would expected. other then that, if i were to remove driver1 and have just in the if statement testRun(localList, driver), it'll run to the point where it failed to find what it needs to find in the setUp method where it is trying to log in via driver.findElement with error as no such element: Unable to locate element.
the element is there with thread.sleep(10000)....

any idea or information as to why such case is going sour would be awesome.

Comment: You answering yourself here: "The whole purpose of the void testRun is to not return any expected value" - You declared the return type as void... What do you expect to happen when you try to assign the return value(`void`) to the `driver` variables?

Comment: In resume, what you are doing in `driver=testRun(...)` is the same as doing `boolean flag = "hello"`

Comment: `driver1= testRun(localList, driver);` should be `testRun(localList, driver);` and so on.   Those `driver1`, `driver2` and `driver3` variables appear to be unnecessary ... and it also looks like you didn't declare them.

Comment: @aran i see what you mean, perfect example/logic

Comment: @StephenC my apologies, driver1 - 3 is declared in the global variable forgot to added in above
Thank you for the quick responses everyone.

Comment: @TrongNguyen no worries, you asked correctly so you'll always have some help here